# Can EnumSet return values in written order?

Tags: java, loops, enums, set, enumset

I have an EnumSet

```
public static Set<T> getTypes() {
    return EnumSet.of(
            TYPE_1,
            TYPE_2,
            TYPE_3
            );
}
```

And i want to get the values from it with a getter method

When i try to get the values in my program with a foreach loop they always come in wrong order.
Is there a way to get them in correct order as written above?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the "wrong order"?

Comment: A Set usually doesn't have an order. A `TreeSet` has an order.

Comment: Use Enum.values() instead of an EnumSet:

Comment: Can you add the whole code of the class?

Comment: @Sweeper I think enum-constants in the method were provided in the order that differs from the natural ordering. And OP was expected this custom order to be preserved. But `EnumSet` stores enum members ordered precisely as they were declared in the enum.

Answer (score 2):

The order of elements in the `EnumSet` is the same as the natural ordering of the enum constants (i.e. the order of their declaration).

```
EnumSet
    .of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
THURSDAY
FRIDAY
SATURDAY
```

If you need the order that differs from the natural ordering, you can switch to using a `List` instead of a `Set`:

```
List
    .of(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.FRIDAY, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
SATURDAY
FRIDAY
THURSDAY
```

Or if you need `Set` as a type, you can introduce a property responsible for ordering in your `enum` and make use of the `TreeSet` providing a `Comparator` which is based on this property.

Consider the following dummy `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE(3), TWO(2), THREE(1);
    private int order;

    MyEnum(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }
}
```

Example of storing the enum members into a `TreeSet`:

```
Stream.of(MyEnum.ONE, MyEnum.TWO, MyEnum.THREE)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
        () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyEnum::getOrder))
    ))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
THREE
TWO
ONE
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you want a `Set` to keep the order in which elements were added, there's one obvious choice: `LinkedHashSet`. That's the only `Set` implementation in the JDK that explicitly states that it preserves insertion order (unless you tell it to use last-access order).

Comment: I don't know how I've overlooked this simple option. That's definitely a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is not keeping sort, so rather than it use `List` like:

```
public static List<T> getTypes() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            TYPE_1,
            TYPE_2,
            TYPE_3
    );
}
```